# Understand Go proxy failures when routing

Tags: go, ssl, proxy, tls1.2

I have a simple Go proxy like so. I want to proxy requests through to it and modify the responses of certain websites. These websites run over TLS, but my proxy is just a local server.

```
func main() {
    target, _ := url.Parse("https://www.google.com")

    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(target)
    proxy.ModifyResponse = rewriteBody

    http.Handle("/", proxy)
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", proxy)
}
```

Result: 404 error as shown in the following screenshot:
[image]

From my understanding, the proxy server would initiate the request and close the request, then return the response after modification. I'm not sure what would fail here. Am I missing something w.r.t to forwarding headers to where this request is failing?

### Edit

I've gotten the routing working. Originally, I was interested in modifying the response, but not seeing any change except I see the `Magical` header.

```
func modifyResponse() func(*http.Response) error {
    return func(resp *http.Response) error {
        resp.Header.Set("X-Proxy", "Magical")

        b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        b = bytes.Replace(b, []byte("About"), []byte("Modified String Test"), -1) // replace html

        body := ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(b))
        resp.Body = body
        resp.ContentLength = int64(len(b))
        resp.Header.Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(b)))
        resp.Body.Close()
        return nil
    }
}

func main() {
    target, _ := url.Parse("https://www.google.com")

    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(target)
    director := proxy.Director
    proxy.Director = func(r *http.Request) {
        director(r)
        r.Host = r.URL.Hostname()
    }
    proxy.ModifyResponse = modifyResponse()

    http.Handle("/", proxy)
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", proxy)
}
```

Comment: First step is to eliminate things that are not causing the problem. Try doing the same setup as above, but without modifying the response. Does that give the same error? If so, it has nothing to do with your attempt at rewriting the body.

Comment: The same issue persist independent of modifying the body. I'm just curious why this would be the case

Comment: Ok, but then it's better to remove the body rewriting from your question. It's a red-herring and it will not lead to good answers as people will focus on that instead of the general reverse-proxying.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Sounds good, I've modified the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical problem is mentioned in the documentation, but it's not clear from the documentation how to deal with it exactly:

> NewSingleHostReverseProxy does not rewrite the Host header. To rewrite
> Host headers, use ReverseProxy directly with a custom Director policy.

https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httputil#NewSingleHostReverseProxy

You don't have the use `ReverseProxy` directly. You can still use `NewSingleHostReverseProxy` and adapt the `Director` function like this:

```
func main() {
    target, _ := url.Parse("https://www.google.com")

    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(target)
    director := proxy.Director
    proxy.Director = func(r *http.Request) {
            director(r)
            r.Host = r.URL.Hostname() // Adjust Host
    }
    http.Handle("/", proxy)
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", proxy)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example! I'll definitely read more into the documentation this evening. To my OP I modified, it's interesting I can't override the response with `ModifyResponse`. I've added your sample modification to the post.